# Javascript is saying function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Just trying to create a simple counter with two buttons, one to add 1 the other to subtract one. I'm using JS and HTML. JS is saying both add() and sub() are not functions. This code works on codepen.io, JSFiddle, and JSHint just says "two unused variables".

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="button">
    <h1>Click Me</h1>
    <p>Number<button id="add" onclick="add()">+</button></p>
    <span id="result"></span>    
    <button id="sub" onclick="sub()">-</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var x = 0


function add(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x+=1;
}

function sub(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x-=1;
}
```

Comment: Because you used JsHint, It is only for javascript it dose not checks HTML and  knows it is used in HTML .It only find problem in Js code

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this way:

```js
var x = 0

function add() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x += 1;
}

function sub() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x -= 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="button">
    <h1>Click Me</h1>
    <p>Number<button id="add" onclick="add()">+</button></p>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <button id="sub" onclick="sub()">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should write JavaScript between `<script></script>` tags

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="button">
    <h1>Click Me</h1>
    <p>Number<button id="add" onclick="add()">+</button></p>
    <span id="result"></span>    
    <button id="sub" onclick="sub()">-</button>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
    var x = 0

    function add(){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x+=1;
    }

    function sub(){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x-=1;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using assing operator twice in the same line without semicolon.

Like below, You had to assign operator in the same line for each function.
In the code it is similar to saying
b = a = a + 1

```js
var x = 0


function add(){
x+=1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x.toString() 
}

function sub(){
 
x-=1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  x.toString()  
}
```

If you still like to use in the same line
You can find this one useful.

```
var x = 0


function add(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (++x).toString();
}

function sub(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (--x).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one,

var x = 0

```
function add(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (++x).toString();
}

function sub(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (--x).toString();
}
```